# jquery-mobile functionality and style fail

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'd like to know, why after tapping the button styles are ruined, as is shown on screenshots? And also text doesn't change, only after second tap.

Here are screenshots:
[image: before tapping]
[image: after tapping]
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
#pause
{
color:black;
font-size: 40px;    

}
</style>
<script>
$('#pause').live('tap', function(event){

    if ($('#pause').text() == "Start")
    {
        $('#pause').text("Pause");
    }

    else
    {
        $('#pause').text("Start");
    }


});
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div data-role="page" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="button"  id="pause"> Start </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, you are directly applying text() method of on your button ID. If you inspect element, you will see jquery-mobile adds sub elements in your button-div.

Try this:

```
$('#pause .ui-btn-text').text("Pause");
```

Live Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/nachiket/ww7Sc/